# Disable :.format routes in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, formatting, ruby-on-rails-3

Could you tell me how to disable the .:format options in rails routes? I only need html...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In 3.1.1 at least you can add , `:format => false` to the end of the route.

Found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints
under section 3.11 Route Globbing

eg..

```
match '*pages' => 'pages#show', :format => false
```

Which would allow params[:pages] to include a period.

Answer (score 16):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

This will constrain your routes to accept only html format:

```
constraints :format => "html" do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

However, it won't remove `(.:format)` part from your `rake routes` output.

Comment: I know I'm late, but with rails 3.2.13 this causes requests coming from curl to render a 404 error, and my website was totally wiped out from google ...

Answer (score 14):

You can wrap you routes around a scope (Rails 4):

```
scope format: false do
  # your routes here
end
```

Comment: exactly what I was searching, thanks a lot! Btw, working in Rails 5, too.

Comment: Works for Rails 6 too!

Answer (score 4):

If you want pretty URLs and you don't like `:format => false` you might try this:

```
# :format must match the empty string
constraints :format => // do
  resources :monkeys
end
```

Even using `with_options`, the `:format => false` option is cumbersome, especially if you have a lot of routes.