# Rails FriendlyId with URLs within URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

My app caches web pages

On pages#new, when you submit a URL (without the `http://` prefix) a page is created and you're redirected to the show, something like `pages/4` where 4 is the ID

I'm trying to add friendly_id but am running into issues after adding `extend FriendlyId` and `friendly_id :url` to my `Page` model

If I supply "yahoo.com", the redirect goes to page/yahoo.com. yahoo.com is interpreted as `{"id"=>"yahoo", "format"=>"com"}` and rails tells me `Couldn't find Page with id=yahoo`

If I supply "yahoo.com/index.html", the redirect goes to page/yahoo.com/index.html but then I simply get `No route matches [GET] "/pages/yahoo.com/index.html"`

How do you think I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A period in a rails route denotes a format (.json, .html, .csv etc.). In order for a route to contain a period, you need to set the `format` option on the route to false in your `config/routes.rb` file.

This answer is borrowed from [Disable :.format routes in rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579652/disable-format-routes-in-rails3).

```
match '*pages' => 'pages#show', :format => false
```

Or (resourceful):

```
constraints :format => // do
  resources :pages
end
```

As for [friendly_id](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id), have you run the migrations to add the `:slug` column to the `Page` model?

For your example, friendly_id takes the `:url` column, makes it a friendly URL and then updates your Page instance with the correct `:slug` value. I suspect that friendly_id would likely replace periods with underscores but I did not verify this.

If you do not want to use the `:slug` column and you already have a `:url` column then you need to define it as such:

```
friendly_id :url, use: [:slugged], slug_column: :url
```

... specifically, the `slug_column` argument.

Comment: Thanks.

I've overridden `normalize_friendly_id` in my `Page` model so that it does nothing (because I want my urls to be like `/page/apple.com`, not `/page/apple-com` - I'm using the resourceful version of the route but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting the `GET` error again for some reason