# Rails Friendly id Fullstops

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, friendly-id

I am using Friendly id to allow custom queries, from the username, in my Rails app.

So say the User's username is `loremipsum`

rails would display this `http://localhost:3000/users/loremipsum`, and this works perfectly fine

but say the User's username is `lorem.ipsum` or `lorem-ipsum`

How could I make rails display, `lorem.ipsum` or `lorem-ipsum` in the url, because it currently takes the first part, and then says `Couldn't find User with id=lorem`

My Users controller

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def index

    @users = User.all


    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @movies }
    end
  end

    def search

    @movies = @search.result

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @movies }
    end
  end
  def show

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    @movies = @search.result

  end

  def sign_up
    @user = User.new

  end

  def sign_in

  end
  def create

    @user = User.create( params[:user] )
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def edit

  @user = @current_user
end

  def update


    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end



  def destroy

    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User destroyed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end


  def edit 

  end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using slug for handle it, you should be able to define this on the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged

  def normalize_friendly_id(string)
    super.upcase.gsub("-", ".")
   end
end
```

reference : [customizing friendly_id slugs](http://fedible.org/posts/customizing-friendly_id-slugs)

Change `User.find` to `User.friendly.find` in your controller

```
User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

[Quick Start Using Friendly_id](https://github.com/FriendlyId/friendly_id#rails-quickstart)

Comment: Have you attribute slug (slug:string) on your user model?

Comment: Yes i have
rails g migration add_slug_to_users slug:string

Comment: Ok sure, Added it to the question

Comment: Now i get this undefined method `friendly' for #<Class:0x007fb15bfa20a8>

Comment: Have you `gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.0"` on your `gemfile`?

Answer (score 0):

This is more likely a routing issue as rails is passing through `lorem` as `params[:id]` and `ipsum` as format.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781314/308701 explains how to disable this, however the caveat is that you won't be able to request other formats such as `xml`, `json` etc ...