# How to set a url routing in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to set this routing:

```
http://localhost:3000/sites/search/www.google.com
```

My config/routes.rb

```
resources :sites, only: [:index] do
  collection do
    get 'search/:url', to: 'sites#search'
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
GET    /v1/sites/search/:url(.:format)                          v1/sites#search {:format=>:json}
```

Controller

```
def search
  @url = params[:url]
end
```

But when I access from URI

```
http://localhost:3000/sites/search/www.google.com
```

Got

```
{
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] \"/sites/search/www.google.com\">",
    "traces": {
        "Application Trace": [],
```

Comment: For anything with a `.` in the path you'll need to use `*url` to grab it all or else the `(:format)` part will grab things like `.com`.

Comment: @tadman You are right! `get 'search/*url', to: 'sites#search'` works well. Could you write it as an answer?

Comment: Oh wait, I got an URL as `"www.google"` but not a full domain.

Comment: You may need to tack on `params[:format]`. If you can get it working, add a self-answer with the full method.

Comment: Should I do as `@url = params[:url] + '.' + params[:format]` ? It can show all the things.

Comment: It's worth a shot, yeah. Just realized you can also [disable `:format`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579652/disable-format-routes-in-rails3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `.` in a url has a specific meaning, and hence can't be used directly. To handle all possible URLs in your queries, you should encode the urls before sending them in your query parameters. So

```
http://localhost:3000/sites/search/www.google.com
```

will become

```
http://localhost:3000/sites/search/www%2Egoogle%2Ecom
```

---

Edit:
There's actually a better solution that is more Railsy. By default, Rails expects the `.` to be a separator in your URL. However Rails allows you to define the format expected for your parameters using [constraints](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints).

So if you update your route definition by adding a regex constraint for the `url` parameter,

```
get 'search/:url', to: 'sites#search', constraints: { url: /.*/ }
```

you should now be able to handle even URLs like,

```
http://localhost:3000/sites/search/www.google.com
```